# How to prevent Teamviewer 6.0.9947 from starting with Windows?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, boot, teamviewer

How to prevent Teamviewer from starting with Windows?

It's not in MSCONFIG.EXE's startup and it's not in start menu's startup directory and I can't find option to disable that in the program.

Comment: kinda unexpected, I perused all teamviewer options like crazy to find it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902).

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I had the same issue and all the answers I read were inaccurate. There is no way to stop the auto start up from the TV ui.
If on Windows, the fix is to set start up to "manual" in windows services.
In XP:
Control panel » admin tools » services
Scroll down to Team Viewer
Right click » properties
Set start up to "manual" and click "stop" the service.

Comment: This was at -1, but it is the actual answer to the question - TeamViewer *does* have an option 'Start TeamViewer with Windows' but deselecting that doesn't keep the TeamViewer service, which is fairly memory-hungry, from starting.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Experience suggests you must have installed Teamviewer Host - designed for incoming connections only.

This version doesn't have the checkbox for "Start with Windows".

To easily get the option you're looking for just uninstall your current version and reinstall the full blown Teamviewer which *does* have the checkbox in options.

Answer (score 2):

In order to stop and shut down the program, go to the Extras Menu and select Options. In the options menu - under General, deselect the box next to Start TeamViewer with Windows. That will mean the program has to be manually started when your machine boots up.